# How to pass a pointer to an integer without a temporary variable?

Tags: c++, temporary

In a number of languages from my past, there is a way to pass an integer constant/literal as a reference to avoid the unnecessary creation of exteremely short-lived variables to functions. A great example is the reuse variable of a setsockopt call. For example

```
int reuseVal = 1;    
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuseVal, sizeof (reuseVal));
```

Some languages let you do the following

```
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, %ref(1), sizeof (int));
```

Is there a similar method available in C++?

Comment: That's not a reference, that's a pointer.

Comment: Ok, the question still stands.

Comment: I don't think so, but in C you could do `(int []){ 1 }`.

Comment: Yep, that one bombs on compiling. Tried that already, but thank you. Has to pass the C++ compiler's scrutiny.

Comment: I wonder ... `std::make_unique<int>(1).get()`?

Comment: Holy Smokin' Frejoles!!! That one complied... let me check functionality... If it works, I owe you a case of your favorite beer!!

Comment: @melpomene I would firstly even check if the standard allows what you put. I am guessing you are returning a pointer to a freed integer. I can't even understand why you would be recommending this in the first place as OPs initial post is the correct and the best way to do what he is asking. std::make_unique is literally worthless in this context.

Comment: I would also like to add that these are micro-optimizations that likely will do absolutely nothing on any modern compiler except possibly make the situation worse.

Comment: @MaxKunes: The `unique_ptr` trick is guaranteed to work, as the lifetime of the `unique_ptr` backing `make_unique` will survive until the call to `setsockopt` returns (example: https://www.ideone.com/Gg2gOr).

Comment: @Travis Gockel testing that on one compiler doesn't necessarily hold up on every compiler. I've seen many an example where the lifetime of these types of objects varies immensely across various compilers.

Comment: Bingo! Works like a champ. Very, very much appreciated! By the way, to show my age, the %ref directive can be found in the old OpenVMS language BLISS-32... Ha!

Comment: @MaxKunes None of this is an "optimization". Heck, `unique_ptr` goes through dynamic memory allocation; if anything, it'll be slower than a local variable. That's not the point at all.

Comment: @melpomene The OP could have definitely implied that. 'unnecessary creation of extremely short-lived variables to functions'. That is my point. I see no benefit in using unique_ptr in the first place.

Comment: @MaxKunes If you've seen a compiler where this code doesn't work, it wasn't a C++ compiler. See [\[class.temporary\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#4): "*Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.*" That's been there since C++98.

Comment: @MaxKunes: It isn't "testing that on one compiler," it's a little-known behavior guaranteed by the standard. §6.6.7/4 states "Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created."

Comment: That's a neat trick, [but it's a bit heavy](https://godbolt.org/z/-KgquW). I thought it would optimize better than that.

Comment: @melpomene Thank you to whomever (melpomene ?) changed the title to reflect the correct terminology.

Comment: @user4581301: GCC and Clang both understand `malloc`/`free` as special operators. What's really interesting is if the compiler sees how `func` is defined, it changes the behavior ([example -- change `INLINE_FUNC`](https://godbolt.org/z/Q3gKpX)). I believe this is because `func` is allowed to look at `i` as a position instead of only at `*i`. If it sees your program isn't using the pointer, it can remove the allocation. Of course, you can still see it isn't as smart about `operator new`.

Comment: IMO the original code is simple and uncomplicated, which trumps any fancy helper class code golf trickery

Comment: Hello everyone, why can't we just pass the int as a reference to the calling function? I'm missing something here is it?

Comment: @Destructor: Where in the question do you see any parameters to a calling function?  If you mean the function being called, `setsockopt` is OS-provided and you can't change its argument types to a reference.

Comment: @Ben Ohhh got it. Thanks :)

Comment: It used to be that you could use `std::addressof<const int>(1)` but since C++17 there's a deleted overload that matches temporaries.

Answer (score 2):

There is not something built-in to C++ that does what you want, but it is easy to build one yourself (with extra logging for clarity):

```
template <typename T>
class holster
{
public:
    using value_type = T;

    template <typename... U>
    holster(U&&... args)
        : _val(std::forward<U>(args)...)
    {
        std::cout << "CTOR: holster" << std::endl;
    }

    ~holster()
    {
        std::cout << "DTOR: holster" << std::endl;
    }

    value_type* ptr() { return &_val; }

private:
    value_type _val;
};
```

Usage of this type is fairly simple:

```
struct thing
{
    thing()
    {
        std::cout << "CTOR: thing" << std::endl;
    }

    ~thing()
    {
        std::cout << "DTOR: thing" << std::endl;
    }
};

void foo(thing*)
{
    std::cout << "in foo" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo(holster<thing>().ptr());
    return 0;
}
```

To expand back out to your original example:

```
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, holster<int>(1).ptr(), sizeof (int));
```

---

Why does this work? A little-known feature of C++ lifetimes is that any temporary created to pass to a function are lifetime-extended for the duration of the function. The referent (`holster::_val`) is *guaranteed* to continue existing until `foo` returns and will be properly destroyed before the next full-expression is evaluated (in this case, before the `;`).

> ### [§6.6.7/4 [class.temporary]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#4)
>
> When an implementation introduces a temporary object of a class that has a non-trivial constructor ([[class.default.ctor]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.default.ctor), [[class.copy.ctor]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor)), it shall ensure that a constructor is called for the temporary object.
>   Similarly, the destructor shall be called for a temporary with a non-trivial destructor ([[class.dtor]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor)).
>   **Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression ([[intro.execution]](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution)) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.**
>   This is true even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception.
>   The value computations and side effects of destroying a temporary object are associated only with the full-expression, not with any specific subexpression.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly. In C you could use a compound literal (e.g. `(int []){ 1 }`), but that's not available in C++.

However, you can write a helper function as follows:

```
template<typename T>
struct temp_holder {
    T data;
    explicit temp_holder(T x) : data(x) {}
    T *ptr() { return &data; }
    const T *ptr() const { return &data; }
};

template<typename T>
temp_holder<T> make_temporary(T x) {
    temp_holder<T> tmp(x);
    return tmp;
}
```

And now you can do:

```
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, make_temporary(1).ptr(), sizeof (int));
```

In my tests with g++ this generates identical code to the `int reuseVal = 1` / `&reuseVal` version at any optimization level above 0 (i.e. `-O`, `-O2`, or `-O3`).

If you want to avoid having to define a new type and function, you can slightly abuse the standard library:

```
#include <memory>

setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, std::make_unique<int>(1).get(), sizeof (int));
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that it goes through dynamic memory allocation (plus (exception-safe) deallocation), so it is likely to be slower than the custom type (or just declaring a temporary variable).

Comment: You can add a `T* operator&() { return &data;}` and then it simplifies to `setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &make_temporary(1), sizeof(int));`

Comment: @RaymondChen Overloading `operator&` doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: Well, to be fair, the entire exercise doesn't feel right. (Also, with C++17, you don't need `make_temporary`; you can just write `temp_holder(1)` and [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) does the work for you.)

Answer (score 0):

`setsockopt()` requires a pointer to an allocated variable. Whether that variable is allocated statically or dynamically, it doesn't matter, as long as it has an accessible memory address that can be obtained at runtime and then dereferenced to access the data at that address.

Your original code does *exactly* that. It declares a local variable that is allocated in automatic memory (ie in the call stack of the calling thread), then uses the address-of `&` operator to get the memory address of that variable, and passes that address to `setsockopt()`. Things don't get much simpler than that.

The other answers you have been given are just more complex variations of this same theme - assigning a value to a variable and then taking the address of that variable.

To conserve the ALREADY EXTREMELY MINIMAL overhead of declaring a variable of primitive type and populating it with data, you could perform that statically at compile-time using a global variable that is initialized once at program startup and reused whenever needed, eg:

```
const int cReuseAddrOn = 1;

void setReuseAddrOn(int s)
{
    setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &cReuseAddrOn, sizeof (cReuseAddrOn));
}
```

I would imaging that things like `%ref(1)` in other languages are likely to be implemented similar to this, creating a reference to a temporarily allocated variable or to a reusable literal constant.

Comment: I think it's not the run-time overhead that's the problem (as you say, it's negligible) so much as risk of accidentally calling the function with incorrect arguments.  `setsockopt()/getsockopt()` is not a particularly coder-friendly API to use (which of course is why everybody writes a wrapper function and calls that instead :) )

Comment: @JeremyFriesner creating a reference/pointer to a literal/constant doesn't stop the user from still being able to pass an incorrect argument to `(get|set)sockopt()`.

Comment: @RemyLebau yes, that's 100% true.  The only way to make `(get|set)sockopt()` compile-time error-resistant is to not call them directly.